# How to add a UIProgressview to Theos app

Tags: ios, progress, theos

I'm wanting to add a progress screen for when users press the Install Theos button they know what's going on.

Here's my code:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation RootViewController
- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]];

    UIButton *installButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    installButton.frame = CGRectMake(21, 80, 100, 35);
    [installButton setTitle:@"Install Theos" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:installButton];
    [installButton addTarget:self action:@selector(installButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)installButtonPressed
{
system("apt-get update");
system("apt-get install perl net.howett.theos");
}
@end
```

I'd also like to know if my background image code is correct?

Comment: What do you want the progress bar to display? The status of the `apt-get install` command? And regarding your background image code - does it compile and run, and work as expected? What do you mean by "is correct"?

Comment: Yes progress of the apt-get install and the background image code for the app self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background"]]; because when I try to make the package theos is giving me error 2 but not saying what the error is

Comment: This isn't enough information. How is 'error 2' being displayed? Is there no other error or message? Have you tried searching for the scenarios in which `apt-get` will report `error 2`?

Comment: Error 2 is coming from Theos and it doesn't say what it is.

Comment: I just want a progress screen to show when the Install Theos button is pressed